# Input strings and display reversely using for loops with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string, for-loop

What I want to do is to enter a number of loops , then all the entered words will be displayed on reverse . I tried numbers to display on reverse , and it works . But , I don't know what to change in the codes . I'm not good in c++ , so I'm practicing . Thanks for helping me =)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    string a[y];
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> x;
    x=x-1;
    for (y=0; y<=x; y++)
    {
        cout << y+1 << ". ";
        cin >> a[y];
    }
    for (y=x; y>=0; y--)
    {
        cout << a[y] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do yo want to input a string and then print that string in reverse order ??

Comment: This is undefined: `string a[y];` you'll need to put this line at least after `cin >> x; x=x-1;`

Comment: @kempoy211 As I pointed out in my post C++ has no Variable Length Arrays. So you marked an answer as the best that uses VLA. That is the code presented in the answer does not satisfy the C++ Standard and can be not compiled by other compilers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm sorry, I thought I could mark two answers. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ptogram is invalid. For example you are declaring array a

```
string a[y];
```

while variable y was not initialized

```
int x, y;
```

C++ does not allow to define Variable Length Arrays.

So instead of an array it would be better to use standard container `std::vector`

The program could look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Enter number: ";

    size_t n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.reserve( n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << i + 1 << ". ";

        std::string s;
        std::cin >> s;
        v.push_back( s );
    }

    for ( size_t i = n; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        std::cout << v[i-1] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example if the input looks like

```
4
Welcome
to
Stackoverflow
kempoy211
```

then the output will be

```
kempoy211
Stackoverflow
to
Welcome
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH ! Do you know what's the best website to learn more on C++ ? Sorry for follow-up question . Thank you ! =)

Comment: @kempoy211 I do not use web sites to learn C++. I only see through web sites when I have a question. So I can not advice a web site for learning C++.

Comment: Can I send to the database all entered strings using the preprocessor fstream ? And then , when I want to view my database , can I send them back to the program ?  I mean , display or view it .

Comment: @kempoy211 What is "preprocessor fstream"? Of course you can write amd read files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::reverse from algorithm library in C++. With that you don't need to write these bulky loops

EDITED:-

If you just want a reverse traversal and print your string below is the Pseudo code:-

```
for ( each string str in array )
{
for ( int index = str.length()-1; index >= 0; index -- )
cout << str[index];
}
cout <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Not really, `std::reverse` will change the container, the OP asks for a reverse traversal

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> x;
    string a[x];  //this should be placed after cin as x will then be initialized
for (y=0; y<x; y++)
    {
        cout << y+1 << ". ";
        cin >> a[y];
    }
for (y=x-1; y>=0; y--)  // x-1 because array index starts from 0 to x-1 and not 0 to x
    {
        cout << a[y] << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter Number: 5
1. one
2. two
3. three
4. four
5. five
five
four
three
two
one
```

Comment: Can I send the entered & scanned string to the database using the preprocessor fstream ? TIA.